# Rspec redirect_to routes are failing expectations (or misparsed?), how come?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rspec, actioncontroller

It seems my rspec route for :controller => 'phones', :action => 'edit' works...it should be 'phones/123/edit', and IS according to rspec tests and rake routes. But when I create a redirect_to expectation, the expectation fails.

Here's the routes test for the url:

```
    it "maps #edit" do
      route_for(:controller => "phones", :action => "edit", :id => "1").should == "/phones/1/edit"
    end #THIS TEST PASSES
```

Here's the expectation that fails:

```
    put :update, :id => "1", :phone => {}
    response.should redirect_to :controller => 'phones', :action => 'edit'
```

And this is the message I get in the tests:

```
expected redirect to {:controller=>"phones", :action=>"edit"},
got redirect to "http://test.host/phones/1089/edit" # BUT THIS THE URL I WAS EXPECTING!
```

What the schiznits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is failing is that you are missing the id in your expectation. It should be:

```
response.should redirect_to :controller => 'phones', :action => 'edit', :id=>1
```

Comment: Close enough...I artually ended up having to use the mock_phone.id like this:

    response.should redirect_to :controller => 'phones', :action => 'edit', :id=>wock_phone.id

Thanks Pell! By the way, have I seen you around anywhere? I get a feeling I've seen you on Github or some other forums.